# Express and mongodb relationships

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to make relationship between my table but when i insert a new Personnage i have an error. I don't understand why i have this error just with "ethnie".

Thank you for your help

This is my tables,

```js
const royaume = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  nom_royaume: String,
  image_royaume:  String,
  description_royaume: String 
})

const Royaume = mongoose.model('Royaume', royaume)

const jeu = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  nom_jeu: String,
  image_jeu: String
})

const Jeu = mongoose.model('Jeu', jeu)

const ethnie = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  nom_ethnie: String,
  image_ethnie: String,
  description_ethnie: String 
})

const Ethnie = mongoose.model('Ethnie', ethnie)

const personnage = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id : String,
  nom_personnage: String,
  image_personnage: String,
  description_personnage: String,
  Jeux: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Jeu'}],
  Ethnie: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Ethnie'},
  Royaume: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Royaume', required : true}
})

const Personnage = mongoose.model('Personnage', personnage)
```

and this is my new Personnage

```js
new Personnage({
      _id : "personnage_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10000))).toString(),
      nom_personnage : req.body.inputNom,
      image_personnage : req.body.inputImage,
      description_personnage : req.body.inputDesc,
      Jeux : [],
      Royaume : req.body.id_royaume,
      Ethnie : req.body.id_ethnie
 })
```

**The error :**

```
{ _id: 'royaume_1453',
  nom_royaume: 'Sarasaland',
  image_royaume:   'https://66.media.tumblr.com/0697b65d318912d7ef010c1d396e7d69/tumblr_pomnpy6Tqf1w3693do2_500.png',
  description_royaume: 'Le royaume de Sarasaland',
  __v: 0 }

{ _id: 'ethnie_861',
  nom_ethnie: 'Koopa',
  image_ethnie:
   'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/mario/images/f/f0/Koopa-0.png/revision/latest?cb=20181117162734&path-prefix=fr',
  description_ethnie: 'L\'ethnie des koopas',
  __v: 0 }

{ ValidationError: Personnage validation failed: Ethnie: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ethnie_861" at path "Ethnie"
    at ValidationError.inspect (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:59:24)
    at formatValue (internal/util/inspect.js:493:31)
    at inspect (internal/util/inspect.js:191:10)
    at Object.formatWithOptions (util.js:84:12)
    at Console.(anonymous function) (console.js:196:15)
    at Console.warn (console.js:213:31)
    at Personnage.save.then.catch.err (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\server.js:413:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errors:
   { Ethnie:
      { CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ethnie_861" at path "Ethnie"
          at new CastError (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
          at model.$set (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1022:7)
          at model._handleIndex (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:797:14)
          at model.$set (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:743:22)
          at model.Document (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:119:12)
          at model.Model (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:93:12)
          at new model (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4502:13)
          at router.route.get.post (C:\Users\jerom\Desktop\Projet\projet_nodejs\server.js:401:5)
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        message:
         'Cast to ObjectID failed for value "ethnie_861" at path "Ethnie"',
        name: 'CastError',
        stringValue: '"ethnie_861"',
        kind: 'ObjectID',
        value: 'ethnie_861',
        path: 'Ethnie',
        reason: [MongooseError] } },
  _message: 'Personnage validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

[the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpuQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

when assigning a Mongo ObjectId. use `ObjectId` type exported by mongoose.

you can assign like :

```
new Personnage({
      _id : "personnage_" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(10000))).toString(),
      nom_personnage : req.body.inputNom,
      image_personnage : req.body.inputImage,
      description_personnage : req.body.inputDesc,
      Jeux : [],
      Royaume : Types.ObjectId( req.body.id_royaume),
      Ethnie : Types.ObjectId( req.body.id_ethnie)
 })
```

Comment: i have a new error now : 
req.body.id_royaume = "royaume_1453"
ValidationError: Personnage validation failed: Royaume: Path `Royaume` is required.

Answer (score 0):

_id is dynamically generated by mongodb driver,and this error is mongoose error, so your schema should be like

```
 const royaume = new mongoose.Schema({
  nom_royaume: String,
  image_royaume:  String,
  description_royaume: String 
})

const Royaume = mongoose.model('Royaume', royaume)

const jeu = new mongoose.Schema({
  nom_jeu: String,
  image_jeu: String
})

const Jeu = mongoose.model('Jeu', jeu)

const ethnie = new mongoose.Schema({
  nom_ethnie: String,
  image_ethnie: String,
  description_ethnie: String 
})

const Ethnie = mongoose.model('Ethnie', ethnie)

const personnage = new mongoose.Schema({
  nom_personnage: String,
  image_personnage: String,
  description_personnage: String,
  Jeux: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Jeu'}],
  Ethnie: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Ethnie'},
  Royaume: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Royaume', required : true}
})

const Personnage = mongoose.model('Personnage', personnage)
```

add Data on your schema

```
new Personnage({
      nom_personnage : req.body.inputNom,
      image_personnage : req.body.inputImage,
      description_personnage : req.body.inputDesc,
      Jeux : [],
      Royaume : req.body.id_royaume,
      Ethnie : req.body.id_ethnie
 })
```

and if you want custom id then add another field on Schema

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question. Why do we need to store this id in an ObjectId field? Couldn't a string field be enough?

Comment: the _id is a 12 byte bson string and consist of
4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,3-byte machine identifier, 2-byte process id,3-byte counter, starting with a random value

,this is unique and this will help you for update and findByID